# Omit `<span>` inside `<div>` when using `getSelection()`

Tags: javascript, html, selection

**Situation:**

I have this following HTML:

```
<!--First div-->
<div>cat elephant</div>
```

I use `window.getSelection().focusOffset` to get the character index which is clicked:

```
let index = window.getSelection().focusOffset;
```

Ex: If I click on the "c" character of the string inside the `div`, the `index` will be `1`; the "e" character, the `index` will be `5`.

**Problem:**

I wrap each word of the above `div` in a `span` like this:

```
<!--Second div-->
<div><span>cat</span> <span>elephant</span></div>
```

And use the same script to get character index then the output is unexpected.

If I click on the "c" character, the index is still `1`; but the "e" character, the index is `1` instead of `5`.

**What I want:**

I want the second `div` has the same behavior as the first `div` when I click on the character to get it index.

**Edit:**

- I also use `anchorOffset`, but it returns same result.

Comment: Do you understand why you are getting `1` instead of `5`? When you use `<span>`, `cat` and `elephant` are no longer part of the same DOM text node.

Comment: I know, but I want they to behave like they are in same DOM text node when I use `getSelection()`.

Comment: you can check which dom element was clicked and based on this you can get the index of the span. so if it was the second span that's clicked you know that the user clicked the word `elephant`